# Dice game program will not run but will not stop at 5 rolls

Tags: c, loops, srand

I am getting two errors:

```
Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
```

and:

```
Error 4 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Since I can not get the program to run, I am also unsure if Case 'A' will generate a roll or not. I don't want to display the results in Case 'A' and my gut feeling is `scanf` should not be there but I could be wrong.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define PAUSE system("pause")


int main ()
{
    int diceOne, diceTwo, diceThree;
    int currentDiceSum=0, totalDiceSum=0;
    char choice;
    int count = 0;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    diceOne      =rand()%6+1;
    diceTwo      =rand()%6+1;
    diceThree    =rand()%6+1;

    do {
        printf("\n Roll the dice, but you only get 5 rolls! You can't play forever, you know. \n");

        printf("Main Menu\n");
        printf("A.Roll the Dice\n");
        printf("B.Display the Result of Last Roll\n");
        printf("C.Quit\n");

        printf("Enter your choice:   ");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        choice = toupper(choice);

        switch(choice) {
            case 'A': 
                printf("Dice are rolled!'\n");

                diceOne      =rand()%6+1;
                diceTwo      =rand()%6+1;
                diceThree    =rand()%6+1;


                count ++;
                break;
            case 'B':  
                if (count = 0) {
                    printf("Please roll the dice atleast once\n");
                }  else {
                    printf("Dice 1: %d\n", diceOne);
                    printf("Dice 2: %d\n", diceTwo);
                    printf("Dice 2: %d\n", diceThree);

                    currentDiceSum = diceOne + diceTwo + diceThree;
                    printf("Dice Total: %d\n", currentDiceSum);
                    totalDiceSum+= currentDiceSum;
                }
                break;
            case 'C':
                if (count == 5)  
                    printf("Number of rolls: %d\n", count);

                printf("Total of all dice for all rolls:%d\n",totalDiceSum);
                printf("Goodbye, hope to see you again!!!\n");
                PAUSE;
                break;

            default:
                printf("Was not a valid menu choice (Please enter A,B,C\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice!= 'C'); 
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly; it is un-readable. The error looks as if there is some library missing. I do not know windows, but: could it be you are compiling a windows-appication instead of a console app?

Comment: @Olaf: I have an edit in the queue that fixes the formatting.

Comment: Also, you're assigning `count = 0` in `case 'B':` when you probably mean to be checking if `count == 0`

Comment: which compiler? which platform? not enough info

Comment: Your scanf overwrites the random values that you just generated.  Also some of your printfs are missing newlines.

Comment: `scanf("%d","%d","%d", &diceOne, &diceTwo, &diceThree);` --> `scanf("%d" "%d" "%d", &diceOne, &diceTwo, &diceThree);`  (take out 2 commas)

Comment: Hint: `rand() % 6` will very likely not give a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

> Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

This is linker error message.

I think you have created a GUI windows application as it requires `WinMain` as entry point.

You should change `subsystem` to `console` in linker settings.

If you are using Visual Studio then go to

`Project properties` then `c\c++` then `linker ->system-> Subsystem :CONSOLE(/SUBSYSTEM CONSOLE)`

For code blocks -

Go to the `Project` then `Properties`. Under the `Build targets` tab,see combo box  `Type`. For the `Debug` target, set it  "Console application"

Plus your  program works fine .It dosen't have any additional errors and also  it does not crash.